# How to check time if its at the specific time, then do an action

Tags: php, javascript

I already have time function and already be able to check its at the time I want then
It will change value of the input text;

HOWEVER, when I try to do the action, it would not work.

I have time function here 
then if the time is at 2:30:35 PM then text value change to 1

```
if(buff=="2:30:35 PM")
{document.getElementById("text").value = 1;}
```

BUT when I want to check if the value of the text is 1 it would not do the action.

```
<input id= "text" name="test" type="text" value="">
<?php
if (isset($_GET['test']))
{
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Could not connect to host.");
  mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link) or die("Could not find database.");
  $query = "UPDATE table SET something='0'";
  $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("Data not found.");
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error, it just wouldn't update the table.

Comment: Why don't you have where condition in the update query?

Comment: I do but its really long so I didn't want to post it up, 
I don't think its the $query that is wrong, it could be something to do with if (isset($_GET['test']))
but here is my code

$query = "UPDATE display SET 8_9='0', 9_10='0', 10_11='0', 11_12='0', 12_13='0', 13_14='0', 14_15='0', 15_16='0', 16_17='0', 17_18='0' WHERE PKslot='PK1' OR PKslot='PK2' OR PKSlot='PK3' OR PKSlot='PK4' OR PKSlot='PK5' OR PKSlot='PK6' OR PKSlot='PK7' OR PKSlot='PK8' OR PKSlot='PK9' OR PKSlot='PK10'";

Comment: if time listener works, then in case you get right time call ajax function that updates table. This code looks weird. How do you trigger  get method call?

Comment: what is 8_9 in your table? Is this the column name?

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['test']))` should be `if (isset($_POST['test']))`???

Comment: I am a noob to this, 
but here is what happen in the code

I have a function that will show the time 
and within the function I added 

if(buff=="2:30:35 PM")
{document.getElementById("text").value = 1;}

where buff = hrs+":"+t_min+":"+t_seg+meridian;
from the function

then the value of the input type text change to 1

then if (isset($_GET['test'])) is supposedly be checking
if the value of the text is inserted or change

so if its change then UPDATE the table

Comment: 8_9, 9_10 .... are my columns yes, sorry if its confusing.

Comment: cryptic: I just change it still wouldn't update my table.

Comment: get or post method will not run my some magic, if if(buff=="2:30:35 PM") works (check with alert) then call ajax function (easier with jQuery) to do the works.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
//mktime(hour,min,sec,month,day_of_month,year); returns time() value for that date/time
if (time() < mktime(14,30,35,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'))) {
    //This will run if its earlier then 2:30:35 PM
    //do smth
}
if (time() > mktime(14,30,35,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'))) {
    //This will run if its later then 2:30:35 PM
    //do smth
}
```

Sources:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php